# How to create objects on the fly in python?

Tags: python, django, object

How do I create objects on the fly in Python? I often want to pass information to my Django templates which is formatted like this:

```
{'test': [a1, a2, b2], 'test2': 'something else', 'test3': 1}
```

which makes the template look untidy. so I think it's better to just create an object which is like:

```
class testclass():
    self.test = [a1,a2,b2]
    self.test2 = 'someting else'
    self.test3 = 1
testobj = testclass()
```

so I can do:

```
{{ testobj.test }}
{{ testobj.test2 }}
{{ testobj.test3 }}
```

instead of calling the dictionary.

Since I just need that object once, is it possible to create it without writing a class first? Is there any short-hand code? Is it ok to do it like that or is it bad Python?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Django templates, the dot notation (`testobj.test`) can resolve to the Python's `[]` operator. This means that all you need is an ordinary dict:

```
testobj = {'test':[a1,a2,b2], 'test2':'something else', 'test3':1}
```

Pass it as `testobj` variable to your template and you can freely use `{{ testobj.test }}` and similar expressions inside your template. They will be translated to `testobj['test']`. No dedicated class is needed here.

Comment: thank you, that solved the django related part of my problem :) i just checked the other answer because people coming here from google would probably prefer to see the python related answer.

Comment: @JasonTS, the python related answer would be to use Karl Knechtel's answer of `collections.namedtuple`.

Answer (score 34):

You can use built-in [type function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type):

```
testobj = type('testclass', (object,), 
                 {'test':[a1,a2,b2], 'test2':'something else', 'test3':1})()
```

But in this specific case (data object for Django templates), you should use @Xion's solution.

Comment: Please don't do this. Simple is better than complex.

Comment: @number5 I will vote for your answer if you also suggest not to use this code! (at least not for this specific case)

Comment: Although this is really handy for creating ad hoc objects for stubbing during testing, i.e. from a dictionary.  Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

There is another solution in [Python 3.3+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)  `types.SimpleNamespace`

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
test_obj = SimpleNamespace(a=1, b=lambda: {'hello': 42})

test_obj.a
test_obj.b()
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: Allows inheritance?

Answer (score 3):

use building function type: [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

```
>>> class X:
...     a = 1
...
>>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

first and second X are identical

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rogue, minimalist way to create an object. [A class is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/673991), so just commandeer the class definition syntax as if it were a Python **object literal**:

```
class testobj(object):
    test = [a1,a2,b2]
    test2 = 'something else'
    test3 = 1
```

Class variables are the members of the object, and are easily referenced:

```
assert testobj.test3 == 1
```

This is weird, a class never used as a class: it's never instantiated. But it's a low-clutter way to make an ad hoc, singleton object: **The class itself is your object.**

Comment: Note thant the class as an object have large memory footprint and sensible amount of time for it's creation.

Comment: @intellimath your point that a class comes with a lot of baggage is a good one, and one should be aware of its consequences. I would note that computer memory gets cheaper while **human memory trends ever more precious**. A singleton object that's not used repetitively has little cost. A lean syntax that's quick to read and understand has solid benefits.

Answer (score 2):

if you just need a "QuickRecord" you can simply declare a empty class
and you can use it without having to instantiate an object...
(just seize the dynamic features of python language... "á la Javascript")

```
# create an empty class...
class c1:pass

# then just add/change fields at your will
c1.a = "a-field"
c1.b = 1
c1.b += 10
print( c1.a, " -> ", c1.b )

# this has even the 'benesse' of easealy taking a 
# snapshot whenever you want

c2 = c1()
print( c2.a, " -> ", c2.b )
```

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of completeness, there is also `recordclass`:

```
from recordclass import recordclass
Test = recordclass('Test', ['test', 'test1', 'test2'])
foo = Test(test=['a1','a2','b2'], test1='someting else', test2=1)

print(foo.test)
.. ['a1', 'a2', 'b2']
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below also require a class to be created however it is shorter:

```
 >>>d = {'test':['a1','a2','b2'], 'test2':'something else', 'test3':1}
 >>> class Test(object):
 ...  def __init__(self):
 ...   self.__dict__.update(d)
 >>> a = Test()
 >>> a.test
 ['a1', 'a2', 'b2']
 >>> a.test2
 'something else'
```