# Assigning values from dictionary to object

Tags: python

I very often need to do something like this:

```
"Some dictionary with values obtained somehow (e.g. submitted form values)"
my_dict = {
    'name': 'John',
    'surname': 'Doe',
    'age': 27,
    'hair_color': 'green',
}

"object person is some instance of class representing person"
person.name = my_dict['name']
person.surname = my_dict['surname']
person.age = my_dict['age']
person.hair_color = my_dict['hair_color']
```

I think this is a lot of repetition. What approach do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for attr, val in my_dict.items():
    setattr(person, attr, val)
```

If `my_dict` might contain any keys that you don't want to copy to `person`, create a list of keys you do want to copy and do something like this:

```
key_list = ['name', 'surname', 'age', 'hair_color']
for attr in key_list:
    setattr(person, attr, my_dict[attr])
```

Comment: note: make sure you filter/santizie my_dict (restrict the keys), otherwise the user can update arbitrary attributes.

Comment: to restrict the keys you could use an explicit whitelist such as `key_list` even if `my_dict` has no unused keys.

Answer (score 1):

As an instance's attributes can be accessed via a dictionary, so use `instance.__dict__`:

```
>>> for item in my_dict:
        person.__dict__[item]=my_dict[item]
```

Comment: This bypasses setter properties and `__setattr__`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good Q/A for this already: [How to create objects on the fly in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575895/how-to-create-objects-on-the-fly-in-python)

In your case:

```
person = type('Person', (object,), my_dict)
print person.name
```