# What is a good way to create objects with methods on the fly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've seen few questions with similar title but none of them seems suitable for me.

I'd like to create python objects, **possibly with methods**, on the fly with clean and "pythonic" syntax. What I have so far is:

```
import types

class QuickObject:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def with_methods(self, **kwargs):
        for name, method in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[name] = types.MethodType(method, self)
        return self
```

Possible usages:

```
ob = QuickObject(x=10, y=20)
print(ob.x, ob.y)
```

```
ob = QuickObject(x=10, y=20).with_methods(sum=lambda s: s.x + s.y)
print(ob.x, ob.y, ob.sum())
```

It works and looks clear but seems a little bit bizarre and I believe there's a better way to achieve this than my definition of `QuickObject` class.

I am aware of `namedtuple` but it's immutable, does not go with methods and it's not that cool because it has to be defined beforehand for every object with different fields.

Built-in dictionaries also does not provide syntax for method calling nor let to access data with `dictionary.key` syntax without custom dict subclass.

**TLDR**: I am looking for a recipe for on-the-fly objects with:

- mutable fields,
- methods,
- nice `ClassName(field1=value, field2=value, ...)` syntax.

---

Further reading:

- [How to use a dot "." to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary)
- [How to create objects on the fly in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575895/how-to-create-objects-on-the-fly-in-python)
- [Using `type`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/type) (external link)

Comment: Your solution seems pretty simple. Is there anything in particular why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, it works well. I am not sure if it's a good way to bound methods with `types.MethodType`. I am also curious if  I'm not reinventing a wheel - maybe there's a more efficient way in a standard module or available in some third-party package.